# Target case-insensitive schemes with URI::regexp?

Tags: ruby

I have this code to remove URIs using these schemes:

```
htmldoc.gsub(/#{URI::regexp(['http', 'https', 'ftp', 'mailto'])}/, '')
```

However, it won't detect a capitalized URI like `HTTP` or `Http` unless I add them to the array.

I tried adding the case-insensitive flag `i` to the regex, but it didn't work.

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`URI::regexp`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#regexp-method) calls the default parser's [`make_regexp`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/RFC2396_Parser.html#make_regexp-method) which in turn passes the given arguments to [`Regexp::union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Regexp.html#union-method) and according to its docs: (emphasis mine)

> The patterns can be Regexp objects, in which case **their options will be preserved**, or Strings.

Applied to your problem:

```
pattern = URI::regexp([/http/i, /https/i, /ftp/i, /mailto/i])

htmldoc = <<-HTML
<html>
<body>
  <a href="https://example.com">here</a>
  <a href="HTTPS://example.com">here</a>
</body>
</html>
HTML

puts htmldoc.gsub(pattern, '')
```

Output:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <a href="">here</a>
  <a href="">here</a>
</body>
</html>
```